# Jenkins fails to start after restart because of google login plugin had an exception

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins version: Jenkins ver. 2.32.1
Google Login Plugin version: 1.3

I got the following error after I restart my jenkins, can anyone suggest me how to solve it?

The thing is :

- I already make sure that in plugins directory I had the google-login plugin enabled
- I didn't change anything on the plugins, just straight restart
- It's been so long since I restart my jenkins

```
    hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:248)
    Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
        at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:47)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1110)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:926)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:231)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:161)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3015)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1100(Jenkins.java:326)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:3033)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:1086)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm : org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
    cause-message       : org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm
    class               : hudson.model.Hudson
    required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
    converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
    path                : /hudson/securityRealm
    line number         : 485
    version             : not available
    -------------------------------
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:356)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
        at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:114)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
        at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:159)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.googlelogin.GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:282)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:43)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:48)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:461)
        at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:327)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: Your config *might* have gotten corrupted: `Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` (if we were to believe the error message).

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is check read/write permission settings on `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`, then remove the xml in `/var/lib/jenkins/` that has the plugin's name in its filename. (backup it before just in case)